# Rewriting the text of a button on every sync

Tags: android, android-button

In my app I have a button that has a text and a variable attached to it.. for example - "inbox 20" where 20 is a variable.

Every minute I do a sync on a separate thread and get the new value of the inbox messages.

Whenever I get the new value, I do

```
b.setText("Inbox" + numMails); //where numMails is an int retrieved from the server.
```

My question is, is there any way to keep the "Inbox" part static and there forever, and just add the numMails ?

Comment: You can use two TextViews, one for the "Inbox" text, and other for the variable

Comment: This is the text of the button.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that detail.

Comment: In that case, I think there is no way. Why you want this? You can use `String.format` instead + operator.

Answer (score 1):

As `Button`'s text cannot be updated partially, it's not possible.

However I assume that you want to achieve this just because of not to rewrite `"Inbox " +` part.

So you can achieve this by extracting a method like this:

```
private void setInboxButtonText(int numMails) {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   sb.append("Inbox ");
   sb.append(String.valueOf(numMails));
   b.setText(sb.toString());
}
```

and use this method wherever you update that `Button`'s text.

Furthermore, if you are looking for more abstract structure then I suggest you to extend `android.widget.Button` class like this:

```
public class InboxButton extends Button {
   @Override
   public void setText(int numMails) {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       sb.append("Inbox ");
       sb.append(String.valueOf(numMails));
       super.setText(sb.toString());
   }
}
```

and use this class while defining your *Inbox Button*.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
b.setText(b.getText().split(" ")[0] + " " + numMails);
```

Comment: same same. as if we didnt gain anything.no ?

Comment: Of course, it's very similar to the original code. However, it's a way not to repeat the text "Inbox" if, for instance, it has already been defined in the activity layout.